# Can a child process which was started by a process in JOB, set JOB properties to breakaway from job?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, visual-c++

A child process is part of job and started by a process which creates the job.
The parent process has already not set JOB properties to allow breakaway from job. "JOB_OBJECT_LIMIT_BREAKAWAY_OK" flag is required to set on JOB to allow child processes to breakaway from job but it is not set.

Can child process change this job properties and set flag JOB_OBJECT_LIMIT_BREAKAWAY_OK so that it or it's child processes can run free from JOB.
Searched online but haven't found anywhere whether this can be done.

Already referred links

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/procthread/job-objects and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/procthread/process-creation-flags

doesn't say if we can do that. Or if required then how to do that.

I wrote a sample application where parent process creates a job without JOB_OBJECT_LIMIT_BREAKAWAY_OK flag. And wrote sample app which gets started by parent. In this child I tried to set JOB properties like below:

```
if (bInJob)
{
    JOBOBJECT_EXTENDED_LIMIT_INFORMATION info1 = {};
    QueryInformationJobObject(NULL, JobObjectBasicLimitInformation, &info1.BasicLimitInformation, sizeof(info1.BasicLimitInformation), NULL);
    DWORD dwLimitFlags = info1.BasicLimitInformation.LimitFlags;

    SetLastError(0);
    info1.BasicLimitInformation.LimitFlags |= JOB_OBJECT_LIMIT_BREAKAWAY_OK;
    if (SetInformationJobObject(NULL, JobObjectExtendedLimitInformation, &info1, sizeof(info1)))
    {
        cout << "failed";
    }
    DWORD fileError = GetLastError();

    JOBOBJECT_BASIC_LIMIT_INFORMATION info = {};
    QueryInformationJobObject(NULL, JobObjectBasicLimitInformation, &info, sizeof(info), NULL);
    dwLimitFlags = info.LimitFlags;
}
```

It doesn't work and JOB properties remained unchanged.

Comment: `SetInformationJobObject` not accept `NULL` in place job handle, unlike `QueryInformationJobObject` which accept it. as result your call to `SetInformationJobObject` will fail with `ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE`. so you need have job handle for call `SetInformationJobObject`. but *An application cannot obtain a handle to the job object in which it is running unless it has the name of the job object. However, an application can call the QueryInformationJobObject function with NULL to obtain information about the job object.*

Comment: Even if the child process could get a handle, it propably doesn't have access rights to modify the job object anyway. It wouldn't make much sense if child processes could break free from job object so easily.

Comment: @zett42 - access right was encoded in handle - if we can get handle with `JOB_OBJECT_SET_ATTRIBUTES` access right - we can change job settings. no matter from which process this will be called

Comment: @RbMm _"You must set security limitations individually for each process associated with a job object, rather than setting them for the job object itself. For information, see Process Security and Access Rights."_ see [Job Object Security and Access Rights](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/ProcThread/job-object-security-and-access-rights)

Comment: @zett42 - and so what ? how this is related ? handle - this is pointer to object (with strong reference) + granted access (which is allowed do over this pointer). when we pass handle to any api - it first convert handle to pointer via `ObReferenceObjectByHandle` with requested access check. then we work direct with object pointer. some time system check privilege of calling tread too for some operations. but not in case `JOB_OBJECT_LIMIT_BREAKAWAY_OK`. what is your quota mean is unclear

Comment: @zett42 - i can guess that msdn mean - need set security for every process handle separate, from job handle (process and job different objects), but anyway for  me not clear what here they try to say. but this not related to - who can set `JOB_OBJECT_LIMIT_BREAKAWAY_OK` for job. all what we need here - job handle with `JOB_OBJECT_SET_ATTRIBUTES` access right. from which process will be called `SetInformationJobObject` - does not matter

Comment: @RbMm checked QueryInformationJobObject() and it doesn't have options to get job handle or job name.

Comment: @Vinod - and so what ? are i say that it have such option ?

Comment: @RbMm I think the quote is related to `JobObjectSecurityLimitInformation`, which was only available for WinXP / Server2003 and not related to security of job object itself, only for process security. I just misunderstood this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

for set `JOB_OBJECT_LIMIT_BREAKAWAY_OK` you need call [`SetInformationJobObject`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686216(v=vs.85).aspx)

for call [`SetInformationJobObject`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686216(v=vs.85).aspx) you need handle to the job whose limits are being set.

but you pass `NULL` here in place handle. as result you must got `ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE` at this point.

from [`IsProcessInJob`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684127(v=vs.85).aspx)

> An application **cannot** obtain a handle to the job object in which
>   it is running unless it has the name of the job object. However, an
>   application can call the [`QueryInformationJobObject`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684925(v=vs.85).aspx) function
>   with `NULL` to obtain information about the job object.

so system special not return to you handle of job object in which you running. this is by design. if child can remove self from job, this serious kill sense of job, for restrict child processes.

Comment: Assuming the parent process is still running and has a handle for the job, the child could enumerate all handles in the system (or just the parent process via [`PssCaptureSnapshot`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/api/processsnapshot/nf-processsnapshot-psscapturesnapshot) in Windows 8.1+); duplicate each job handle to itself; check whether it's in the job via `IsProcessInJob`; and if so, and if allowed, modify the job to allow breakaway. If successful, the program can subsequently break free by respawning itself as a new process.

Comment: @eryksun - yes. possible enumerate handles of parent and found opened jobs. but parent can close job handle just after assign child to it. as result this not always possible

Comment: Yes, this scenario is best case. The parent could also keep a duplicate handle with restricted access (e.g. if the job is kill-on-close) and set the object security to limit access of subsequently duplicated handles.

Comment: @eryksun *duplicate handle with restricted access* - but we anyway can duplicate such handle with `JOB_OBJECT_ALL_ACCESS`

Comment: Not if the object security disallows it.

Comment: @eryksun - but for job this is possible - `if (HANDLE hJob = CreateJobObjectW(0, 0))
 {
  HANDLE h1,h2;
  if (DuplicateHandle(GetCurrentProcess(),hJob, GetCurrentProcess(), &h1, SYNCHRONIZE,0,0))
  {
   if (DuplicateHandle(GetCurrentProcess(),h1, GetCurrentProcess(), &h2, JOB_OBJECT_ALL_ACCESS,0,0))
   {
    CloseHandle(h2);
   }
   CloseHandle(h1);
  }
  CloseHandle(hJob);
 }`

Comment: Duplicating a handle can only grant additional access that's allowed by the object security. This applies to Job objects. Also, for object types that have a private security method (e.g. File, Key), a duplicate handle can never have additional access.

Comment: @eryksun - but i just in test duplicate job object handle with `SYNCHRONIZE` only access (`0x100000` ) to `JOB_OBJECT_ALL_ACCESS` (`0x1f003f`)

Comment: *In some cases, the new handle can have more access rights than the original handle.*

Comment: That was with the default DACL from your token, not a custom DACL that restricts access.

Comment: @eryksun - yes, you are right ) with `SetKernelObjectSecurity` for set say empty *DACL* - `DuplicateHandle` already failed. lost you second part of initial comment